# Is there a way for a vue component to self-destruct?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I've created a simple alert banner component in vue that has a close button on the top right. I want it to hide itself without any additional code in the parent component. Right now the parent needs to hold the information of whether it is shown or not

```
<alert-banner
   v-if="(warnUser && showWarningBanner)"
   type="warning"
   @close="showWarningBanner = false"
>
   <template v-slot:title>Warning</template>
   <template v-slot:description>This is a warning/template>
</alert-banner>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: real interesting one.. have you tried to set ref on the component and called this.$refs['THE_REF'].destroy()? actually i dont know if it's possible but would love to give a try

Comment: wow i assume my comment is not useful :D i wanted to know the answer and i believe the above is the answer! @Ifaruki

Comment: @Ifaruki thanks for the answer but this is what I'm doing already... just wanted to know if there was an alternative as I need to keep a variable in the parent with the state of the alert which I didn't want to do for something so trivial as showing and hiding an alert

Comment: @valanto hmm if you using vuex you could create an state for your alert. and create an mutation for opening and closing the alert. actually i dont know an another way

Comment: @Ifaruki that would be an option although still sounds like an overkill for what I need it. I think my conclusion is that there is no right and concise way to do it. The v-if/v-show on the parent side is the proper solution as blotted as it may be. Thanks again!